# Different way to bind a scope property to a CSS property?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I'm using **Visual Studio Code** (1.12.2) for a HTML based project that uses Angular. vscode marks the following line as syntactically incorrect, even though from an Angular point of view it is absolutely valid (correct me if I'm wrong):

```
<div class="meeting-header" style="background: {{ meeting.color }}">
```

[image]

I know that `{` and `}` are no valid characters in this context. Still, that makes me wonder whether there is a better way to bind some property in Angular to a CSS property.

#### So the actual question is

Is there another way in Angular to bind a property in the scope to a CSS property?

Comment: you can use ng-style directive. The value of the ng-style attribute must be an object, or an expression returning an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use `ng-style` instead, like this:

```
<div class="meeting-header" ng-style="{background: meeting.color}">
```

Read more about it [in the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use ng-class and have all those neat styling be separated on your .css file?

ref:

[AngularJs 2+](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html)

[AngularJs <2](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)